# Error Mesh in RenderScript android

Tags: android, mesh, renderscript

I created a RenderScript project in eclipse. However, I encountered an error "Can not be resolved Mesh to a type". Can you help me resolved this problem. Thank you very much

This is my .rs file

```
//declare RendorScript Version
#pragma version(1)

//declare package
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.hellors2);

//include graphics library
#include "rs_graphics.rsh"

rs_mesh my_rs_mesh;

void init(){

}

int root(){
    //set background color
    rsgClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    //draw something
    rsgDrawMesh(my_rs_mesh);

    //repeat 20ms
    return 20;
}
```

and error like this
[image]

Comment: Mesh is deprecated, so you really should not be using it.

Comment: I changed Built target is android 3.0 and the error is solved. However, my program stop when initilize script (line 40-Script_mono = new ...). I still can not fix this problem